# onbeforeunload loops and hangs Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, onbeforeunload

I'm using this script to prevent reload and back button navigation of a page to inform the user of if he/she leaves, changes done will be lost.

In Firefox, the problem only seem to occure when hitting the back button. 
The alert dialog box is shown and just keeps on looping back up whether you press "stay" or "leave", and you must force close Firefox.

Is there a better script for this, that actually works in FF?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
   e = e || window.event;

   if (e) {
      e.returnValue = message;
   }

   return message;
};
```

Comment: What behavior do you expect from the script exactly? Just preventing the user from reloading the page..? I'd suggest not touching the browser's default behavior unless it's completely necessary.

Comment: It is necessary. And it works great in Chrome and Safari. I want to inform the user of; if he/she leaves, changes done will be lost. And the user can choose to leave or stay.

Comment: Ok, the only bug is when you press `back` in firefox? Write the exact expected behavior in the question and you'll most likely get good answers..

Comment: Updated. Yes from what I've tested so far, the back button action seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me in firefox and Chrome:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit()
{
   return "Are you sure you want to leave?";
}
</script>
```

Comment: It may be a bug in the browser,have you change the code? If yes update your above code in your post so I can take a look again :)

Comment: Thanks. It's the same code, I use it inside a function, but I've tried it outside the function as well. It seems like if you reload the page and click "leave" in the alert, and then press browser back button, the dialog begins to loop. If you press "stay" at this point several times you might break the loop, but if you press "leave" the loop continue and then it just display a dialog with no info just a cancel and a ok button, and FF needs a force quit.

Comment: you should contact mozilla, because that looks like a browser bug, the code above is right and works in google chrome and safari and its working in the mac version of firefox (followed your actions exactly) so I would say this is a browser bug, and I'm sure mozilla would be happy to hear about it :)

Comment: I will do that. I just found out it's the same problem on this very site. When you ask a new question, and reload the page before posting, the onbeforeinload warning pops up.. and if you leave, reload and hits back, it start to loop here as well. I use Firefox for Mac too, I've tried it on both my computers so it must be a browser bug.